# How to get location from latitude and longitude in android

Tags: android, location

So I have a piece of code I got from the internet that lets me get the latitude and longitude from the current location. What I want now is to get the location of that place. And yes I did allot of research, and got this code from stack overflow from someone that had the same request as me(below). It probably worked for them, but it doesn't work with me. I used an example latitude and longitude because this code wasn't working. The problem is that the addresses is always null. What am I doing wrong? Why isn't geocoder.getFromLocation working? I tried logging addresses aswel, and I get [] as result.

```
private String getCompleteAddressString(double LATITUDE, double LONGITUDE) {
    String strAdd = "";
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(51.977315, 5.921753, 1);
        if (addresses != null) {
            Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
            StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");

            for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
            }
            strAdd = strReturnedAddress.toString();
            Log.w("My Current loction address", "" + strReturnedAddress.toString());
        } else {
            Log.w("My Current loction address", "No Address returned!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.w("My Current loction address", "Canont get Address!");
    }
    return strAdd;
}
```

Comment: What are all things you get it in this `addresses` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Location Utility Class

public class LocationUtility {

private String currentLatitude = "";
private String currentLongitude = "";
private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
private final int TEN_SECOND = 0;
private final int TEN_METRES = 1;
private final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2; // Better Location

String provider;

public LocationUtility(Activity activity) {
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    getCurrentLocation();
}

private boolean isGpsOn;

private void getCurrentLocation() {
    Location gpsLocation = null;
    Location networkLocation = null;
    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(listener);

    /*
     * Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
     * criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
     * criteria.setCostAllowed(false);
     * 
     * String bestProviderName = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,
     * true);
     * 
     * if(bestProviderName!=null) Logger.d("bestProvider",
     * bestProviderName);
     */

    gpsLocation = requestUpdatesFromProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    networkLocation = requestUpdatesFromProvider(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    isGpsOn = true;

    if (gpsLocation != null && networkLocation != null) {
        updateLocation(getBetterLocation(gpsLocation, networkLocation));
    } else if (gpsLocation != null) {
        updateLocation(gpsLocation);
    } else if (networkLocation != null) {
        updateLocation(networkLocation);
    } else {
        isGpsOn = false;
    }
}

public String getCurrentLatitude() {
    return currentLatitude;
}

public String getCurrentLongitude() {
    return currentLongitude;
}

private final LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null)
            updateLocation(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        if (provider != null)
            Logger.d(provider + " provider", "disabled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        if (provider != null)
            Logger.d(provider + " provider", "enabled");

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Logger.d("status", "" + status);
    }
};

/** Checks whether two providers are the same */
private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
    if (provider1 == null) {
        return provider2 == null;
    }
    return provider1.equals(provider2);
}

private Location getBetterLocation(Location newLocation,
        Location currentBestLocation) {
    if (currentBestLocation == null) {
        // A new location is always better than no location
        return newLocation;
    } else if (newLocation == null) {
        // A new location is always better than no location
        return currentBestLocation;
    }

    // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
    long timeDelta = newLocation.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
    boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

    // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use
    // the new location
    // because the user has likely moved.
    if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
        return newLocation;
        // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be
        // worse
    } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
        return currentBestLocation;
    }

    // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
    int accuracyDelta = (int) (newLocation.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation.getAccuracy());
    boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
    boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
    boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

    // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
    boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(newLocation.getProvider(),
            currentBestLocation.getProvider());

    // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and
    // accuracy
    if (isMoreAccurate) {
        return newLocation;
    } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
        return newLocation;
    } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate
            && isFromSameProvider) {
        return newLocation;
    }
    return currentBestLocation;
}

private Location requestUpdatesFromProvider(String provider) {
    Location location = null;
    if (mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, TEN_SECOND,TEN_METRES, listener);
        location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    }
    return location;
}

private void updateLocation(Location location) {
    try {
        Logger.d("new Location",location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude());

        currentLatitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        currentLongitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // if (e != null)
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 */
public boolean isGPSON() {

    return isGpsOn;
}

public void removeUpdates() {
    if (listener != null) {
        try {
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // if (e != null)
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

write this method to get current latitude and longitude

```
public static String[] getLatAndLong(Activity mContext) {
    LocationUtility mLocation = new LocationUtility(mContext);
    return new String[] { String.valueOf(mLocation.getCurrentLatitude()),String.valueOf(mLocation.getCurrentLongitude()),String.valueOf(mLocation.isGPSON()) };
}
```

write this into your main activity where you get location details

```
try {
        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, Long, 1);

        //String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
        //String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
        //String newstring = city.replaceAll(",","");
        //String country = addresses.get(1).getAddressLine(2);

        try {
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() >= 0) {
                strCity = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                strCounty = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                strState = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```